# Prevent inherited test methods to be launched from child

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, selenium, nosetests

I have 2 classes with functional tests

```
class VehicleTest(unittest.TestCase):
      def setUp(self):
          self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

      def test_math(self):
          self.assertEqual(1+1, 2)


class VehicleTestCase2(VehicleTest):
      def setUp(self):
          super(VehicleTestCase2, self).setUp()
          self.do_some_additional_stuff()

      def test_another_math(self):
          self.assertEqual(2+2, 4)
```

As test runner I use `nosetests`. When I go to console in test directory, type `nosetests` and hit ENTER, I see that 3 tests where launched in this order

```
VehicleTest.test_math, VehicleTestCase2.test_another_math, VehicleTest.test_math
```

Question:
How prevent `nosetests` from launching parent class tests from child class? So I have only these tests launched

```
VehicleTest.test_math, VehicleTestCase2.test_another_math
```

I want to exclude inherited by `VehicleTestCase2` tests from launch.

Answer (score 1):

Split `VehicleTest` so that you have a base class that contains only what is common to all classes and create a class that contains `test_math`. Something like:

```
class VehicleTest(unittest.TestCase):
      def setUp(self):
          self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()


class VehicleTestCase1(VehicleTest):
      def test_math(self):
          self.assertEqual(1+1, 2)


class VehicleTestCase2(VehicleTest):
      def setUp(self):
          super(VehicleTestCase2, self).setUp()
          self.do_some_additional_stuff()

      def test_another_math(self):
          self.assertEqual(2+2, 4)
```

`VehicleTest` in the code above is your base class and `VehicleTestCase1` is the new class.

I do not recommend trying to find a trick to have a base class contain a bunch of tests that are later suppressed in some of the derived classes. This would just obscure the logic of your code.